# find the index of very first element that is greater than first limit but less than second limit efficiently

Tags: c++

I need to find the index of very first element in a sorted `std::vector<int>` that is greater than first limit but less than second limit efficiently.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    const int a = 2, b = 4; // a is always less than b
    const std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    // an efficient algo that will return an iterator to the 
    // first element in vec that is greater than a but less than b
    int ans = -1;
    for (const auto x : vec) {
        if (x > a && x < b) {
            ans = x;

            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << ans << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

Comment: @Jarod42 Lower bound would return an iterator to an element equal to `a` too.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think I need both `std::upper_bound` for first limit and `std::lower_bound` for second limit. Am I correct?

Comment: @Harry There's really no need for `lower_bound` for the second limit. Just check what the iterator returned by `upper_bound` is pointing at.

Comment: whats the relevance of the "but less than a second limit" ? EIther the desired element is the first that is greater than the first limit, or it does not exist. You can stop the loop once `x > a` is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::upper_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound):

> Returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range `[first, last)` such that `value < element` (or `comp(value, element)`) is `true` (i.e. strictly greater), or `last` if no such element is found.

```cpp
auto it = std::upper_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), a);
// set `it` to the end iterator if the found value is not less than `b`
if(it != vec.end() && not(*it < b)) it = vec.end();
```